# sails.js heroku blank index.html

Tags: node.js, html, heroku, sails.js

I have successfully deployed my sails.js app on heroku. From the logs I can see that the application is properly lifted. Since I would like to use static .html files, in the /config/views.js I changed my engine like this:

```
engine: {
    ext: 'html',
    fn: require('ejs').renderFile
},
```

Every think works fine locally and my pages are properly served. But on the production site - on heroku - when I hit the site url mysite.herokuapp.com I receive a blank page with no error (e.g 404) in the logs. The file index.html is the assets directory.

What else should I do, or any suggestion on where I may look for to start solving this issue?

Thank you stackoverflow

Comment: Do you have committed last changes?

Comment: Yes I have committed my last changes. I think it should be related to the engine used. But I can't figure out what i am doing wrong

Comment: I mean the view engine